# SaaS LDAP/directory service?

Tags: ldap, saas

I know that my Googling skills are failing me because there **must** be something like this: a simple, easy-to-use remotely hosted directory service (and even better, exposes the user directory through several different interfaces, and SSO).

Do you know of one and/or have one to recommend?

I am looking at Atlassian Crowd - http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview - which comes close with the pluggable interfaces, but it does not implement LDAP. It can only connect to an existing LDAP server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already been discussed on ServerFault, and I think [the answer given here](https://serverfault.com/a/187180/67343) may be a good starting point for your search. It lists 
[Symplified](http://www.symplified.com/main/what-we-do-for-you/products/provisioning/), [Entic.net](http://entic.net/) and [eApps](http://www.eapps.com/applications/openldap-hosting.php).

Comment: Thank you, I'll check those out. I've also had http://www.onelogin.com recommend to me.